# Serialization to byte array of the "same" object on separate JVMs produces different results

Tags: java, serialization, data-integrity

I have a Serializable data structure which I transmit to a remote machine, and I'm trying to use md5 hash to verify the integrity of the remote data.

I noticed that the hash value does not match even though the data looks the same

In order to calculate the hash I'm converting the object (on both local & remote machines) to a byte array using apache 
SerializationUtils.serialize()

Digging further into this I found that the byte arrays don't match.
They Are very similar but not identical.

Can anybody explain why this happens?

**Edit**:

Please see the code Below

I simplified the data structures but the types are the same (I just assume the problem has something to do with the types)

```
// md5 calculation
public HashCode hash(Iterable<MyObject> hostBackups) {
    Hasher hasher = Hashing.md5().newHasher();
    for (MyObject host : hostBackups) {
        hasher.putBytes(SerializationUtils.serialize(host));
    }
    return hasher.hash();
}

// data structures
public class MyObject implements Serializable {
    private final StringId myObjectId;
    private final Map<StringId, ClassA> aMap;   // map implementation is HashMap
    private final Map<LongId, ClassB> bMap;
    private final Map<LongId, ClassC> cMap;

}

public class StringId implements Serializable {
    private final String ip;
}

public class LongId implements Serializable {
    private final long id;
}

public class ClassA implements Serializable {
    private final StringId id;
    private final Serializable value;
    private final long time;

}

public class ClassB implements Serializable {
    private final LongId id1;
    private final LongId id2;
    private final Result result;    // enum
    private final long time;
}

public class ClassC implements Serializable {
    private final StringId id1;
    private final LongId id2;
    private final String s1;
    private final String s2;
    private final boolean aBoolean;
}

public enum Result {}
```

Comment: could you please show more of your code?

Comment: Are you on same versions on both machines?

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. The main point is that ObjectOutputStream doesn't guarantee that the output is the same every time you write an object, so you can't expect it. If you want to know more about your particular case you should post your code.

Comment: As an analogy, it's perfectly valid for different JSON writers to include different or no whitespace for output that is semantically identical.

Comment: @Erwin please see the code in the edited question

Comment: @Sid The code is the same on both machines

Comment: I see a field called `time` in `ClassA and `ClassB`. What does that contain, the current time? In that case you can expect it to be different when you run the serialization at different times.

Comment: @Erwin the time is set on one machine and the object s serialized and transmitted to the other one. So the time value is the same (saw it also with the debugger)

Comment: @Erwin I thought about your first comment again. If "ObjectOutputStream doesn't guarantee that the output is the same every time..." then how can I ever calculate a consistent hash??? According to what you say it may not be consistent even on the same JVM